# Convert array of arrays to array of hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have following array of arrays in Perl that are getting as multiple rows in database.

```
$arrayref = [
    [ 1, "name1",  "name2" ],
    [ 2, "name3",  undef ],
    [ 3, "name5",  "name6" ],
    [ 4, "name10", undef ],
];
```

I want to make this as an array of hashes like this

```
my @array = (
    { id => 1, name => "name1",  l_name => "name2" },
    { id => 2, name => "name3",  l_name => undef },
    { id => 3, name => "name5",  l_name => "name6" },
    { id => 4, name => "name10", l_name => undef },
);
```

Comment: Where do you get your data for your array? Is parsing it into a hash upstream (rather than converting it later) an option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `map {}` to transform array references to hash references,

```
my @cols = qw(id name l_name);

my @array = map { my %h; @h{@cols} = @$_; \%h } @$arrayref;
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( zip );

my @cols = qw(id name l_name);

my @array = zip(\@cols, @$arrayref);
```

Comment: Oh that's very elegant. I like it.

Comment: yes it is. Thanks for that solution. The one i made was a lengthy code

Comment: While this solves the OP's immediate problem, [@Borodin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31988118/100754) solves the real issue.

Answer (score 8):

> I have following array of arrays in Perl that are getting as multiple rows in database

You are presumably calling

```
$sth->fetchall_arrayref();
```

If instead you use an empty anonymous hash as the first parameter

```
$sth->fetchall_arrayref( {} );
```

then DBI will return the data in the format you want as an array of hashes

The DBI documentation describes it [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref)

> If `$slice` is a hash reference, `fetchall_arrayref` fetches each row as a hash reference. If the `$slice` hash is empty then the keys in the hashes have whatever name lettercase is returned by default. (See `FetchHashKeyName` attribute.) If the `$slice` hash is not empty, then it is used as a slice to select individual columns by name. The values of the hash should be set to 1. The key names of the returned hashes match the letter case of the names in the parameter hash, regardless of the `FetchHashKeyName` attribute.
>
> For example, to fetch all fields of every row as a hash ref:
>
> ```
> $tbl_ary_ref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
> ```

Comment: Could you add a link to the DBI documentation? I've never seen that feature.

Comment: @simbabque: Sure, but it's only the `fetchall_arrayref` documentation